# Installing Sql Server Mangement Studio on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, ssms

I am trying to install Sql Server Mangement Studio 2008 onto a Window XP SP3 machine. When I do, it says that I need to install .Net Framework 3.5 SP1. However, I all ready have .Net Framework 4.0 installed.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application targetting .NET 3.5 SP1 need .NET 3.5 SP1 installed. .NET 3.5 SP1 by default installs .NET 2 and .NET 3.0. Basically the base CLR version is .NET 2. .NET 4 is a new version of CLR. Hence applications targetting .NET 4 will need .NET 4 installed and applications targetting older versions will not switch to .NET 4 without recompile.

Answer (score 1):

Most versions of the .Net framework are not cumulative.
You need to install [.Net 3.5 with SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22).